Parametro opcional en Swagger me lo marca como requerido
Buenas estoy usando DelphiMVCFramework  para crear un api y en el siguiente codigo, para establecer un parametro:
 // imprimir avisos


[MVCPath('/hayavisospendientes/($monitor1)/($monitor2)/($monitor3)')]
    [MVCHTTPMethod([httpGET])]
    [MVCSwagSummary('Avisos', 'Imprimir Avisos', '12', false)]
    [MVCSwagResponses(HTTP_STATUS.OK, 'Ok - Avisos devueltos', TRespuestaInt)]
    // parametro optenido por Get
    [MVCSwagParam(plPath, 'monitor1', 'Monitor 1', ptInteger, true, '1')]
    [MVCSwagParam(plPath, 'monitor2', 'Monitor 2', ptInteger, false)]
    [MVCSwagParam(plPath, 'monitor3', 'Monitor 3', ptInteger, false)]
    function GetImprimirAvisos(monitor1: Integer; monitor2: Integer;
      monitor3: Integer): TRespuestaInt;

El quinto parametro lo establezco en false, para decirle a Swagger que no sea requerido. Pero cuando entro a Swagger me sigue apareciendo como que el parametro es requerido.
Alguien podria decirme por que sucede esto.

Aunque monitor2 no es requerido me sigue diciendo que es requerido.

Hombre... un pathParam que está en medio de la ruta siempre debe ser requerido. Cómo vas a llegar a poner el parámetro monitor3 si no pones monitor2???

Si, si eso lo tengo claro, lo que pasa esque he puesto solo lo de monitor2 por que como este me falla tambien y es el primero no llega al tercero. Pero esta puesto como opcional y en el Swagger me sale como requerido por pantalones, segun la documentacion hay una propiedad true o false para requerirlo. Como se pondria opcional?¿¿? podrias decirmelo

actualizo el codigo de ahora de como lo tengo

Lo que estoy intentando decirte es que tu planteamiento es incorrecto. Un pathparam en medio de una ruta jamás puede ser opcional. Lo que estás buscando tal vez sea un queryParam

a vale, te entiendo. OK voy a probar haber y comento. Gracias

Perfecto, muchas gracias. Funcionando.

De nada, pero no necesito que me des las gracias, la mejor manera de agradecer es ayudar a que la pregunta sirva para los demás. Escribe una respuesta indicando cómo lo solucionaste (ejemplificándola con el código por favor) y algún enlace a la documentación si hace falta y luego márcala como aceptada para que todo el mundo sepa que eso funciona :)
